# Creating a self-governing puppetmaster (puppetlabs)

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I am working on my first puppetlabs puppet installation. I have a question concerning the overall setup.

Is the puppetmaster able to govern it's own server as it governs its puppet agents?
Is there any specific trick to this? Do i just install a puppetagent on the same server as the master?

Comment: Yes, the machine hosting the puppetmaster can be managed by its own puppetmaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install puppet agent it does not differ from ant other agent.

So you can do that either by using `puppet apply` on a master node or just adding corresponding `node` section into the main site.pp manifest and invoking `puppet agent -t` or via cron/daemon.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: Upon googling an install guide i tripped over a few worrying issues: http://www.elsotanillo.net/2011/08/installing-puppet-master-and-client-in-the-same-host-the-debian-way/ http://madduck.net/blog/2010.03.11:splitting-puppetd-from-puppetmaster/ where people seems to have problems with exactly this. Is this an issue from older versions, or do i have to heed this and split up working directories, and whatnot?

Comment: From my own experience I had no problems having master and agent on the same node. I use the same manifests to perform automation tasks on master.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will "Jump right in" so to speak :)